# View instead of downloading an image in new chrome tab using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension that will open a link to an image in a new tab.

However I am coming across links that will automatically download the image instead of viewing it in the new chrome tab.

I am using the following code to do create the new tab:

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: url_to_open, active: false});
```

Example of "unviewable" image from vsco: "im.vsco.co/aws-us-west-2/de89e8/880500/627c05d3edd24e3c58174876/vsco_051122.jpg?w=749&dpr=1"

Is there any way to not automatically download the image but view it instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you just use `window.open(url_to_open, '_blank');`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's the same result. Saves instead of viewing.

Comment: The problem is caused by Content-Disposition header. You need to remove it by using chrome.webRequest or chrome.declarativeNetRequest.